# Automatically assigning functions with Python in Pypher

Tags: python, function, neo4j, cypher

I am making a Python script that will take inputs from a .JSON and, using Pypher, automatically create Cypher scripts. This is an example of the .JSON input file:

```
{
    "nodes": [
        {"id": "n1", "type": "AAAA"},
        {"id": "n2", "type": "BBBB"},
        {"id": "n3", "type": "CCCC"}
    ],
    "edges": [
        {"id": "e1", "from": "n2", "to": "n1", "type": "REL1"},
        {"id": "e2", "from": "n2", "to": "n3", "type": "REL2"}
    ],
    "filters": [
        {"id": "f1", "on": "n1", "attribute": "ATT1", "dtype": "int", "operation": "is", "value": "null"},
        {"id": "f2", "on": "n3", "attribute": "ATT1", "dtype": "int", "operation": "is", "value": "null"},
        {"id": "f3", "on": "n1", "attribute": "ATT2", "dtype": "str", "operation": "=", "value": "V"},
        {"id": "f4", "on": "n2", "attribute": "ATT3", "dtype": "str", "operation": "is", "value": "not null"}
    ]
}
```

The RETURN section, among others, will be added later. One of the downsides of the graph I am working with is that every single property, regardless of content, is of the string datatype, and as such I need a way to assign toInteger (and similar) operations automatically. That is the purpose of the "dtype" item in "filters"; "int" means I need toInteger, for example.

One way to do this is with a giant mess of IF statements, which I would rather avoid, especially since "giant mess of IF statements" was my solution for inserting the "operation" item into the code. This is the relevant section of the code:

```
from pypher import Pypher
q = Pypher()

if(len(motif['filters']) >= 1):
    if(motif['filters'][0]['operation'] != 'is'):
        if(motif['filters'][0]['operation'] == '='):
            q.Where(motif['filters'][0]['on']+'.'+motif['filters'][0]['attribute']) == motif['filters'][0]['value']
        elif(motif['filters'][0]['operation'] == '>'):
            q.Where(motif['filters'][0]['on']+'.'+motif['filters'][0]['attribute']) > motif['filters'][0]['value']
        elif(motif['filters'][0]['operation'] == '>='):
            q.Where(motif['filters'][0]['on']+'.'+motif['filters'][0]['attribute']) >= motif['filters'][0]['value']
        elif(motif['filters'][0]['operation'] == '<'):
            q.Where(motif['filters'][0]['on']+'.'+motif['filters'][0]['attribute']) < motif['filters'][0]['value']
        elif(motif['filters'][0]['operation'] == '<='):
            q.Where(motif['filters'][0]['on']+'.'+motif['filters'][0]['attribute']) <= motif['filters'][0]['value']

    elif(motif['filters'][0]['operation'] == 'is'):
        if(motif['filters'][0]['value'] == 'null'):
            q.Where(motif['filters'][0]['on']+'.'+motif['filters'][0]['attribute']).IS_NULL()
        if(motif['filters'][0]['value'] == 'not null'):
            q.Where(motif['filters'][0]['on']+'.'+motif['filters'][0]['attribute']).IS_NOT_NULL()

    if(len(motif['filters']) >= 2):
        for k in range(len(motif['filters'])-1):
            if(motif['filters'][k+1]['operation'] != 'is'):
                if(motif['filters'][k+1]['operation'] == '='):
                    q.And(motif['filters'][k+1]['on']+'.'+motif['filters'][k+1]['attribute']) == motif['filters'][k+1]['value']
                elif(motif['filters'][k+1]['operation'] == '>'):
                    q.And(motif['filters'][k+1]['on']+'.'+motif['filters'][k+1]['attribute']) > motif['filters'][k+1]['value']
                elif(motif['filters'][k+1]['operation'] == '>='):
                    q.And(motif['filters'][k+1]['on']+'.'+motif['filters'][k+1]['attribute']) >= motif['filters'][k+1]['value']
                elif(motif['filters'][k+1]['operation'] == '<'):
                    q.And(motif['filters'][k+1]['on']+'.'+motif['filters'][k+1]['attribute']) < motif['filters'][k+1]['value']
                elif(motif['filters'][k+1]['operation'] == '<='):
                    q.And(motif['filters'][k+1]['on']+'.'+motif['filters'][k+1]['attribute']) <= motif['filters'][k+1]['value']
            else:
                if(motif['filters'][k+1]['value'] == 'null'):
                    q.And(motif['filters'][k+1]['on']+'.'+motif['filters'][k+1]['attribute']).IS_NULL()
                if(motif['filters'][k+1]['value'] == 'not null'):
                    q.And(motif['filters'][k+1]['on']+'.'+motif['filters'][k+1]['attribute']).IS_NOT_NULL()
```

The toInteger (or toFloat, toBoolean, toString) command needs to be applied around the `motif['filters'][k+1]['on']+'.'+motif['filters'][k+1]['attribute']` parts of the script, for example:

```
q.And(__.toInteger(motif['filters'][k+1]['on']+'.'+motif['filters'][k+1]['attribute'])).IS_NULL()
```

Does anyone know how to make Python to automatically assign __.toInteger() (or __.toBoolean, etc.) without making a mess? As well, does anyone know of a way to automatically assign the operators without all the IF statements? Simply putting the operation item in:

```
q.Where(motif['filters'][0]['on']+'.'+motif['filters'][0]['attribute']) motif['filters'][0]['operation'] motif['filters'][0]['value']
```

or

```
q.Where(motif['filters'][0]['on']+'.'+motif['filters'][0]['attribute']) + motif['filters'][0]['operation'] + motif['filters'][0]['value']
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lacking better ideas, my solution is to use a big mess of conditional statements. It works fine, it's just a bit ugly.